# Creating multiple line plots from two variables in R

Tags: r, dataframe, plot

I have a dataset where multiple measurements from multiple research subjects is recorded in three variables, data$id, data$measurment, and the time in days after admission data$day. So the data$id variable is the same for all measurements from the same research subject.

Now I'd like to create a plot with one line plot for each research subject where the measurements are plotted against the days after admission.

What would be the best way to do this without having to reorganize the data into separated sheets for each research subject? I'm a total noob to r and statistics in general so any basic help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With the `ggplot2` package:

`ggplot(data=data, aes(x=day, y=measurement, group=id)) + geom_line()`

Comment: Thank you! Seems to work but the plot becomes quite cluttered and I'd like to change the limits of the x- and y-axis but can't get it done with the xlim and slim commands I'd normally use for plots. Does it work another way with the ggplot2 package? Where should these commands be inserted in the syntax?

Comment: you should read the ggplot manual..  but to change scale limits use `+ scale_x_continuous(limits=...)`